# Processing JS not responding to keyboard input

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I am trying to make a program using Processing JS that draws a space ship and then allows the user to control it using left and right arrows to turn it and z to make it accelerate. I have been using the `keyIsPressed` function like so

```
keyIsPressed = function(){
    if(keyCode === 90){
        println("OK");
        ship.accelerate();
    }
};
```

but the ship does not move and nothing gets printed in by the `println();` when I press z so it must not be activating the function. Does anyone know how to fix this? here is a link to the full code https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-project-asteroids-spaceship/4635808988463104.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, keyIsPressed is a boolean value that is true when the user is pressing any button on the keyboard and false when there is no keys pressed. Basically,

```
var draw = function(){
    if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === 90){
        ship.accelerate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `keyIsPressed` variable is a `boolean` value that's `true` whenever a key is pressed.

If you want a function, you should use the `keyPressed()` function, and you should not specify it inside `draw()`. It should be at the same level as `draw()`.

Also, you used `ship.accerate()`, which isn't a function. You probably meant `ship.accelerate()` instead.

Putting all of that together, it looks like this:

```
draw= function() {
    background(161, 159, 159);

    ship.update();
    ship.display();
    println(ship.position.x);
};

keyPressed = function(){
    if(keyCode === 90){  
        ship.accelerate();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I don´t know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

For functions it is keyPressed, no keyIsPressed.

```
keyPressed = function(){
    if(keyCode === 90){
        println("OK");
        ship.accelerate();
    }
};
```